# Project Euler #82 (Python)

Tags: python

First of all this is the problem : https://projecteuler.net/problem=82 .
This is my code :

```
# https://projecteuler.net/problem=82

matrice = open('matrix3.txt','r').read().split('\n')
m = []
for el in matrice:
    if el=='':
        continue
    tmp = el.split(',')
    m.append(tmp)
matrix = [[0 for i in range(80)]for j in range(80)]
x,y = 0,0
while(True):
    matrix[x][y]=int(m[x][y])
    y+=1
    if y==80:
        y=0
        x+=1
        if x==80:
            break 
tmp = [0]*80
x,y = 0,78
while(True):
    if x==0:
        tmp[x]=min(matrix[x][y+1],matrix[x+1][y]+matrix[x+1][y+1])
    if x==79:
        tmp[x]=min(matrix[x][y+1],matrix[x-1][y]+matrix[x-1][y+1])
    else:
        tmp[x]=min(matrix[x][y+1],matrix[x-1][y]+matrix[x-1][y+1],matrix[x+1][y]+matrix[x+1][y+1])
    x+=1
    if x==80:
        for e in range(80):
            matrix[e][y]+=tmp[e]
        tmp = [0]*80
        x=0
        y+=-1
        if y<0:
            break
minimo = 10**9
for e in range(80):
     if matrix[e][0]<minimo:
        minimo=matrix[e][0]
print(minimo)
```

The idea behind this code is the following:
I start from the 79th column(78th if you start counting from 0) and I calculate the best(the minimal) way to get from any given entry in that column to the column to the right.
When the column is over I replace it with the minimal results I found and I start doing the same with the column to the left.

Is anyone able to help me understand why I get the wrong answer?(I get 262716)

The same code works for the matrix in the example(It works if you change the indeces of course).

Comment: How do you know what the right answer is? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @Emily The website has a form for registered users where you can submit an answer to the problem and see if it was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, your code, and your algorithm correctly, it looks like you aren't actually calculating the best way to get from one column to the next because you're only considering a couple of the possible ways to get to the next column. For example, consider the first iteration (when `y=78`). Then I think what you want is `tmp[0]` to hold the minimum sum for getting from `matrix[0][78]` to anywhere in the 79th column, but you only consider two possibilities: go right, or go down and then go right. What if the best way to get from `matrix[0][78]` to the next column is to go down 6 entries and then go right? Your code will never consider that possibility.

Your code probably works on the small example because it so happens that the minimum path only goes up or down a single time in each column. But I think that's a coincidence (also possibly a poorly chosen example).

One way to solve this problem is using the following approach. When the input is a NxN matrix, define a NxN array `min_path`. We're going to want to fill in `min_path` so that `min_path[x][y]` is the minimum path sum starting in any entry in the first column of the input matrix and ending at `[x][y]`. We fill in one column of `min_path` at a time, starting at the leftmost column. To compute `min_path[i][j]`, we look at all entries in the (j-1)th column of `min_path`, and the cost of getting from each of those entries to (i, j). Here is some Python code showing this solution: https://gist.github.com/estark37/5216851. This is an O(N^4) solution but it can probably be made faster! (maybe by precomputing the results of the `sum_to` calls?)